# php with sphinx&coreseek SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2 @title(key1) & @content(key2) dosen't work

Tags: php, sphinx

I have the following PHP script and am using the sphinx search API.
I want to search for a keyword '有限' in the customer_name column of the MySQL database and another keyword '北京' int the agent_name column of the MySQL database.

**$s = new SphinxClient;

$s->setServer("localhost", 9312);

$s->SetArrayResult(false);

$s->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2);

$s->SetLimits(0,100000,100000,100000);

$s->SetFilterRange("date",1464710400,1471449600);

$result = $s->Query("@customer_name(有限) & @agent_name(北京)", "mysql");**

$result = Array(
    [error] =>
    [warning] =>
    [status] => 0
    [fields] => Array
        (
            [0] => customer_name
        )

```
[attrs] => Array
    (
        [id_a] => 1
        [date] => 1
        [sale_id] => 1
        [sale_group_id] => 1
        [channel_sale_id] => 1
        [channel_sale_group_id] => 1
    )

[matches] => Array
    (
        [216896] => Array
            (
                [weight] => 1455
                [attrs] => Array
                    (
                        [id_a] => 216896
                        [date] => 1471449600
                        [sale_id] => 251
                        [sale_group_id] => 33
                        [channel_sale_id] => 0
                        [channel_sale_group_id] => 0
                    )
```

......  // omitted 
)

```
[total] => 43076
[total_found] => 43076
[time] => 0.088
[words] => Array
    (
        [有限] => Array
            (
                [docs] => 82288
                [hits] => 82288
            )

    )
            )
```

only the keyword '有限' is to be seached.

and one of the result of the customer_name and agent_name is as follow:
cusotmer_name is "上海幻电信息科技有限公司" 
agent_name is "-"

If someone can tell me What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: I have solved the problem, thanks all the same.